# Get transactions for address

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, api, bitcoin-cli

I develop an application (BitBook, https://github.com/C-Otto/BitBook) that helps users track their coins. For this, whenever I reason about some address, I need to consider all transactions that take funds *out of* the address, or pay *into* the address.

With bitcoin-cli I could use the block details (possibly with `getblockfilter`) to find all transactions that pay *into* the address. By adding quite a bit of logic and scanning the complete blockchain, I could then also find addresses that take funds *out of* the address. However, the whole process seems rather involved and slow.

APIs like Blockchair offer convenient endpoints that give me exactly the required information, but considering that I need to keep this information up-to-date (for all addresses that are relevant to the user), I'd like to avoid using such APIs that only offer a limited number of free requests. Aside from that, there's the obvious privacy issue.

My question:

What are other ways to get the necessary information?

- Input: address
- Output: list of transactions paying into the address or taking out of the address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bitcoind` does not have an index by spending/receiving address.

to get transaction by address a different index is needed, examples are electrum server and reimplementations of it (electrumX, electrs), these do require extra storage for their own index.

I personally have a good experience with electrs ([github](https://github.com/romanz/electrs)), it only takes up ~10% of the blockchain size and is fast with queries.

Comment: Thank you. `contrib/history.sh` in the electrs repository is a good starting point and gives exactly the information I need!